# Toolbar цвет текста черный

Tags: android, toolbar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать белым текст, в приложении показывает белым

Comment: всем спасибо, не знаю в чем была проблема, но все решилось заменой файлов styles из другого приложения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

или

```
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(android.graphics.Color.WHITE);
```

или через styles.xml добавляете итем в стиль для AppCompat

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">TITLE_COLOR_GOES_HERE</item>
```

или добавьте в xml в тег toolbar'a

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/oolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: В данном случае, цвет в тулбаре приложения в списке приложений должен, по идее, только через стили задаваться

Comment: Спасибо, первый и второй работают в тулбаре внутри приложения но снаружи тоже самое, 3,4 вообще ничего не меняют(в моем случае). какая нибудь доп. информация нужна для решения проблемы?

Comment: заметил что если тулбар синий то текст черный, а если тулбар черный то текст автоматом становится белым